# Excel - equivalent of Javascript reduce function?

Tags: excel, reduce

Is there an Excel equivalent of the Javascript `reduce` function? Essentially, I want to apply a function to each cell in a range, and then sum up each result.

The reason I ask is because I have the following sheet:

[image: excel screenshot]

For each expense, I'm calculating the "change", i.e. the amount needed to round it up to the nearest pound. I'm then summing that at the bottom.

I want to be able to do this without having the extra column and summing those values.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT(it avoids the need of `Ctrl-Shift-Enter`) and ROUNDUP(just shorter, personal preference):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ROUNDUP(C3:C7,0)-C3:C7)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work with CEILING.MATH too instead of ROUNDUP. I tried something along those lines initially but couldn't figure out what CEILING.MATH was doing when I passed it a range.

Comment: ROUNDUP and CEILING.MATH are similar, I just use ROUNDUP because it is less typing. But either work in this case. @GrantJ

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I just found out there's something called an array formula where you type your formula and then press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` (and it'll put curly brackets around your formula to show that it worked).

So for my example above, I'd type

`=SUM(CEILING.MATH(C3:C7)-C3:C7)`

Then press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` and it'd change it to

`{=SUM(CEILING.MATH(C3:C7)-C3:C7)}`

and that gives me the £2.11 I'm expecting.